# Opening a user profile by default in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there any way to open a user profile by default in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

To put it otherwise, when I launch Dragon, I don't want to have to choose which is a profile to open like in the screenshot below but have one opened by default.

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: What have you tried or researched? Does the manual or web site have any support documents regarding this?

Comment: Try `natspeak.exe /user Francky`

Comment: You can set it by using the Browse to set the profile.

Comment: @CharlieRB I don't think this is in the user manual, but I've just seen it in [DNS admin guide](http://www.nuance.com/ucmprod/groups/corporate/@web-enus/documents/collateral/nc_025639.pdf).

Comment: Sure is. Check page 50 of the [Administrator Manual](http://www.nuance.com/ucmprod/groups/corporate/@web-enus/documents/collateral/nc_025639.pdf). Shows exactly what @techie007 told you to do. :-)

Comment: @CharlieRB Yep, that's what I saw :) Nice documentation, I had never run across it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaturallySpeaking provides a command-line option for picking which user (profile) you want to start as.

The option is `/user`, so create a shortcut to your NetruallySpekaing's `netspeak.exe` and include the argument `/user` followed by the name of the profile you want to load (ie: `Francky`).

[More info](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3088/~/command-line-arguments-for-dragon-naturallyspeaking)

---

From the [Administrator Guide](http://www.nuance.com/ucmprod/groups/corporate/@web-enus/documents/collateral/nc_025639.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct format to load a user called   Michael-V15

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking15\Program\natspeak.exe" /user "Michael-V15"

NOTE:  You must use the "" in this format for it to work   /user "Michael-V15"