# How can I configure Adobe Audition so that it loads a specific session when it starts?

Tags: adobe-audition

How can I configure Adobe Audition so that it loads a specific session when it starts?

For example, I can [configure Dragon NaturallySpeaking so that it opens a given user profile when it starts](https://superuser.com/q/826276/116475). I am looking for something similar for Adobe Audition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I configure Adobe Audition so that it loads a specific session when it starts?

It doesn't seem to be directly possible:

> > Is it possible to execute scripts on wav files using command line parameters?
> >
> > If not, is there a way to automate script execution on files without opening the Audition interface?
>
> No it isn't, I'm afraid. There was a discussion about this some years ago, and the upshot of this was that it might be possible (and probably is, if you put the effort in) to use a third-party batch processor to provide the virtual keystrokes for you. But that's about as far as it goes.

Source [Command Line Parameters | Adobe Community](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/634782)

And:

> You might want to investigate Adobe's automation platform, Adobe CEP Extensions.

Source Comment on [automation - Automating audio processing in Adobe Audition - Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23035/automating-audio-processing-in-adobe-audition)

> **Adobe CEP Extensions, and developing add-ons for Audition**
>
> With the CC 2015.1 release of Audition, we implemented support for
>   third-party integration via the Adobe Context Extensibility Platform
>   (CEP).  This technology allows anyone with some HTML and JavaScript
>   know-how to build integrated panels that extend or supplement the
>   functionality of Adobe applications, offer access to third-party and
>   web technologies without leaving the applications, and allow those
>   services to share Application data and files back-and-forth.  There
>   are already over 1600 addons available for Adobe desktop applications
>   such as Premiere Pro and Photoshop.

Source [Adobe CEP Extensions, and developing add-ons for Audition | Creative Cloud blog by Adobe](https://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/adobe-cep-extensions-and-developing-add-ons-for-audition/)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy: directly open your session file, as shown below.

[image]